# How to apply function to data frame group based on whether the row meets a condition?

Tags: python, group-by

I'm trying to group my df by user and apply weights to each occurrence of that user using the following rules.

1. If the user appears 3 or more times in the df I want to assign:

- a weight of 0.4 the first and last occurrence
- a weight of 0.2/(# of occurences - 2) to each remaining occurence (divide the remaining 20% among all other occurences)

2. If the user appears less than 3 times even weighting is applied: 1/# of occurrences

The final weights should look like this:

| User | Order | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Josh | 1 | 0.4 |
| Josh | 2 | 0.2 |
| Josh | 3 | 0.4 |
| Liam | 1 | 0.4 |
| Liam | 3 | 0.4 |
| Liam | 2 | 0.2 |
| Abby | 1 | 0.5 |
| Abby | 2 | 0.5 |

so far I have done the below, which gives me the result I want in the "final_wt" column, but I wonder if there's a better way to approach this with less intermediate steps?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

# list of name, degree, score
user = ["josh", "josh", "josh", "liam", "liam", "liam", "abby", "abby"]
order = [1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 1, 2]
device = ["a", "a", "a", "b", "a", "b", "c", "a"]
  
# dictionary of lists 
dict = {'user': user, 'order': order, 'device': device} 
    
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
    

def func(T):
    if len(T) < 3:
        return 1/len(T)
    else:
        return 0.2/(len(T)-2)
        

df['wt']= df.groupby('user')['order'].transform(lambda x: func(x))
df['grpsize']= df.groupby('user')['order'].transform(lambda x: len(x))

df['final_wt'] = np.where(
    df['grpsize'] < 3, df['wt'], np.where(
    df['order'] ==1 , 0.4, np.where(
    df['order'] == df['grpsize'] , 0.4, df['wt'])))
```

Is there a way I can modify  .transform() applied to groupby with a condition so I can have the weights calculated in a less hacky way?

Or is there a way I can modify my function to apply to individual group elements as opposed to the group as a whole?

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: FYI: If one parameter is passed into lamba, no need to expand it: `.transform(func)`.

Comment: Oh thanks! That's so helpful - I didn't know that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I improved my solution by doing the following:

```
df['final_wt']= df.groupby('user')['order'].transform(lambda x: 
np.where(((x==1) | (x==len(x)))& (len(x)>2), 0.4, func(x)))
```

Comment: You calculate length of group multiple times including inside your method.

Comment: I know I do. I want to be able to use my method func(T) to look at the individual group elements and see if they are the first or last element (so I don't have to use np.where here) but it seems like my function only works on the group as a whole and doesn't let me consider individual elements. I tried looping over individual elements in the function but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: Do you by any chance know how I can change my function to look at the elements in the group and not just the group as a whole. In this portion of my code it seems as though in the np.where statement x is being treated as both the entire group in (len(x)) and an individual element x ... not sure why that works here but I can't access individual group elements in my function

Answer (score 0):

Consider [**`DataFrame.assign`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) which allows reuse of calculated columns like group size. Also, when `numpy.where` becomes nested, consider [**`numpy.select`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). Below also uses the functional form of [binary operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior) and [comparison operators](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#matching-broadcasting-behavior). Be sure to use a more informative name than `df` (used as `lambda` variable in `assign`)!

```py
...
user_devices_df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'user': user, 'order': order, 'device': device} 
)

user_devices_df = (
    user_devices_df.assign(
        grpsize = lambda df: df.groupby('user')['order'].transform('count'),
        wt = lambda df: np.where(
            df['grpsize'].lt(3),
            df['grpsize'].pow(-1), 
            df['grpsize'].sub(2).pow(-1).mul(0.2)
        ),
        final_wt = lambda df: np.select(
            condlist = [df['grpsize'].lt(3), df['order'].eq(1), df['order'].eq(df['grpsize'])],
            choicelist = [df['wt'], 0.4, 0.4],
            default = df['wt']
        )
    )
)
```

In fact, you can absolve the `wt` calculation, shortening the calculation:

```py
user_devices_df = (
    user_devices_df.assign(
        grpsize = lambda df: df.groupby('user')['order'].transform('count'),
        final_wt = lambda df: np.select(
            condlist = [df['grpsize'].lt(3), df['order'].eq(1), df['order'].eq(df['grpsize'])],
            choicelist = [df['grpsize'].pow(-1), 0.4, 0.4],
            default = df['grpsize'].sub(2).pow(-1).mul(0.2)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I really like this approach. :) Do you know of a way to do it in one step i.e. without first calculating wt and then final_wt or would that complicate things too much?

Comment: Potentially you can since you run on same conditions. See [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77853769/revisions).